# SWIFTUI tex auto animation with colors

Tags: swiftui

How do I make `Text` auto animate with shuffling colors or using LinearGradient to animate text? Or animate borderline of text?

I can animate it on tap gesture but can't figure out a way for it to auto animate, in a `ForEach`.

```
.onAppear() {
    withAnimation(Animation
    .easeInOut(duration: 0.6)
    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
        print("ree: \(self.fadeInOut)")
        self.fadeInOut.toggle()
    }
}
.opacity(self.fadeInOut ? 0 : 1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please attach your original code so we can help

Comment: .onAppear(){
                                            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.6).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)){
                                                print("ree: \(self.fadeInOut)")
                                                self.fadeInOut.toggle()
                                            }
                                        }.opacity(self.fadeInOut ? 0 : 1)